# How do I dynamically add popups to markers using OpenLayers 5 in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, openlayers

I was wondering if someone could lead me in the right direction of dynamically add popups to a map when clicking on a marker. Currently the example on the OpenLayers website only goes through showing one popup at a time.

[http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html?q=popup][1]

I am putting a spin on the example to make it as 'Angular' friendly as possible and to avoid using JQuery. The biggest wall I keep running into is the use of JQuery to complete the task and a lack of a solid example that does multiple markers.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map.on('singleclick', (evt) => {
        this.createPopup(evt);
    })
}

createPopup(evt) {
    const popup = new Overlay({
        insertFirst: false,
        element: this.popupElement.nativeElement,
        positioning: 'bottom-center',
        stopEvent: false,
        offset: [0, -50]
    });

    this.map.addOverlay(popup);

    const feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, (feat) => feat);
    if (feature) {
        const coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        popup.setPosition(coordinates);
        this.displayPopup = true;
    } else {
        this.displayPopup = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the purpose of the example that you attached is to display the possibility to add dynamically markers on the map based on the position you clicked and not the marker that is displayed. It just has one marker by coincidence and you get the popover effect because it is there.

I am not a fan of using jQuery in an Angular project, however, I made a quick try using jQuery's popover method and it worked in case of adding a popup to a single marker by getting the position on the map.

I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve but in case you want to use eventually jQuery by displaying multiple markers you can adjust this code.

I used Angular 6 & OpenLayers 5.

ts

```
...
declare var $: any;
...

layer: TileLayer;
map: Map;
marker;
view: View;
vienna: Overlay;

ngOnInit() {
   ...

   // Popup showing the position the user clicked
   const popup = new Overlay({
      element: document.getElementById('popup')
   });
   this.map.addOverlay(popup);

   this.map.on('click', function(evt) {
      const element = popup.getElement();
      const coordinate = evt.coordinate;
      const hdms = toStringHDMS(toLonLat(coordinate));

      $(element).popover('dispose');
      popup.setPosition(coordinate);
      $(element).popover({
        placement: 'top',
        animation: true,
        html: true,
        content: '<p>The location you clicked was:</p><code>' + hdms + '</code>'
      });
      $(element).popover('show');
   });
 }
```

index.html

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

angular.json

```
"styles": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
      "src/styles.css"
 ],
"scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
]
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7ow0p3onm1)